# How to attach to an existing byobu session or start a new one if there is no session when starting terminal emulator?

Tags: terminal, zsh, tmux, zshrc, byobu

I'm using zsh and [byobu](http://www.byobu.co/) (using the tmux backend).

In my `.zshrc` file I put the following:

```
if which byobu >/dev/null 2>&1; then                                        
    # if not inside a byobu session, and if no session is started,
    # start a new session
    test -z "$TMUX" && (byobu attach || byobu new-session)
fi
```

If I close the terminal emulator I'm using, then open another one, I re-attach to the byobu session I was using and all is fine. However, when I just start my computer, or if I exited byobu (for example by pressing `Ctrl-D` on the last open window), opening a new terminal results in this:

```
[exited]
~$
```

It seems to be because `byobu attach` actually returns something, so `byobu new-session` is never run, but I don't understand why `byobu attach` finds something if I quit byobu (in this case, `$TMUX` is empty).

How can I make sure that a new session of byobu is launched if there is no instance already running?

Thanks!

Comment: `https://www.byobu.org/` is the new URL.  The old one is a squatting, scam, or otherwise meaningless blog site now. `byobu-select-session` might help, although that seems to disable my hotkeys..